# syntax error, unexpected kENSURE js.erb rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a litle problem with my view create.js.erb in my rails project. I want to execute 2 differents block of code if there's a balise with the id JTBDS or not.

Here's my code :

```
if( $("#JTBDS").length ){
  $("#T<%= @current_tweet %>").after("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @jtbd) %>"));
  $("#E<%= @current_tweet %>").hide();

  $(".jtbd_tags").each(function(){
    select($(this)[0].name,
    "http://localhost:3000/search",
    "tag_jtbd");
  });

  tag_button();

  $(".tags").each(function(){
      select($(this)[0].name,
             "http://localhost:3000/adrs",
             "tag");
  });
}

else{
  $("#T<%= @current_tweet %>").before("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @jtbd, :layout => "jtbd_of_tweet",  locals: {jtbd: @jtbd} )) %>");
  $("#E<%= @current_tweet %>").hide();

  $(".jtbd_tags").each(function(){
    select($(this)[0].name,
    "http://localhost:3000/search",
    "tag_jtbd");
  });
}
```

I don't know why but i have an error : syntax error, unexpected kENSURE

I tried to print $("#JTBDS").length with console.log and i have 0 or 1 as expected.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing parens for `escape_javascript` on line 2.

```
 $("#T<%= @current_tweet %>").after("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @jtbd)) %>"));
```